# multiply two images with 50% transparency of one of them in python

Tags: python, opencv, photoshop, alpha, blending

I'm struggling with the task: to multiply two images, 50% transparency of one of them.
That is, to get the result, as if you add two layers in Photoshop, assign opacity = 50% to one of them and set the overlay mode "Multiply"
Using cv2.
Multiplication works, but it is not possible to take into account the alpha channel. I add the alpha channel as another column to the array.

```
texture = cv2.imread(test_texture)[0:2048, 0:2048]
facture = cv2.imread(facture_file)[0:2048, 0:2048]

texture_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(texture, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
texture_rgba[:, :, 3] = 255

facture_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(facture, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
facture_rgba[:, :, 3] = 120

res = multiply(texture_rgba.astype(float)/255 , facture_rgba.astype(float)/255)

cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

in this case, the images are multiplied, but without taking into account the alpha channel

texture:

[image: texture]

facture:

[image: facture]

res:
[image: res]

I'm trying to get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi! added images

Comment: well, **what is the equation for Photoshop's "multiply" blend mode**? if you can find that out (that's "research", your responsibility), your question might get answers.

Comment: Your two images are not the same size. I tried doing the 50% multiply in Photoshop and do not get your desired result.  If you look at it and compare to the basic multiply, I do not see how you can get that kind of result from even a 50% multiply.  Please clarify your PS processing or provide the proper set of images.

Comment: A 50% opacity multiply is just going to darken the multiply from a 100% opacity multiply. It will not change the design pattern. So something is wrong with your desired result image or your processing is different from what you describe.